# Espresso - How to do 2 finger swipes?

Tags: android, automation, android-espresso

I am trying to perform a 2 finger swipe right on an element using Android Espresso.  I know that the following onView(withId(R.id.passengers).swipeRight() will swipe right with one finger.  Is there a way to create a function for 2 finger swipes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Espresso doesn't have this functionality. But, from the [doc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/Swipe.java#78), Swipe action in espresso contains these classes:

- GeneralSwipeAction
- Swipe

You can implement your own 2-finger swipe function by duplicating these classes and inside `sendLinearSwipe` (which performs the single swipe action), try to change it in a way that supports multi swipe action.

What you need is just create another `downEvent` in `sendLinearSwipe` with different start coordinates and try to do the same thing that Espresso already did with `downEvent`.